# Please recommend an editor for beginner

Tags: html, ide, css, editor

Good evening everybody!

I would like to ask you for a recommendation. I am a beginner in coding. I have started to learn HTML,CSS and next my step will be JS. Which application you can recommend me for coding? I mean an editor. I would like something nice, which I can use, for JS as well in future.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: what OS should it run on? What features are important to you? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MS visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is Windows, Linux and OS X, free, well documented & well sported.

> In Visual Studio Code, we have support for almost every major programming language. Several ship in the box, for example, JavaScript, TypeScript, CSS, and HTML but more rich language extensions can be found in the VS Code Marketplace.

Then there are links to extensions for Python, C/C++, C#, java, Go, PHP, Ruby & Rust; no doubt there are many more in the marketplace, but the ons that you currently want are included out of the box.

Comment: Runs on OS X too!  Great software, especially for Python.

Comment: I'm still sticking to PyCharm, but using VS code & PlatformIO for embedded stuff

Comment: I  would suggest editing your answer to include OS X as a supported platform.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Atom editor](https://atom.io/). I use it personally and it is completely free. It comes with auto fill for HTML and CSS as well as you can download free plugins to help with other programming languages although I think it also supports JS by itself.